# Is my generic type a list, or just an item?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a method that takes a generic parameter T.  Internally, to decide what other methods to call, I need to know (without constraining it) if that parameter is a List or just something.

How do I do that?

I've been using

```
var isList = typeof(T).Name.ToLower().Contains("list`1");
```

but that feels like a dirty approach.  What's cleaner?

Comment: Did you try comparing it to another list object type?

Comment: This will fail if you pass it a `NotReallyAList<T>` instance.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean when you say "list"? Do you mean the exact type `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`? Or do you mean anything with 0 or more items? Or any type of collection that can be read as well as updated? etc.

Comment: More specifically, aiming at an IList<>.  Specifically, trying to target what will happen with NHibernate's IQuery.UniqueResult vs IQuery.List()  approaches.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var type = typeof(T);
bool isList = type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>);
```

If you don't need an exact match for List, you might also just check if `typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))`, which many list-like collections implement.

---

If you want to support T being equal to `IList<T2>` directly (so the type parameter T is an interface), then you need to check for that separately (`GetGenericTypeDefinition()` could also return `typeof(IList<>)`).

If you want to support any type T that inherits from any `IList<>`, then you have to get a bit more creative.  You have to enumerate all interfaces, check if they are generic (as above) and then check if the generic type of the interface is `IList<>`.  Also, because the GetInterfaces() call on Type only returns the top-level interfaces, you need to navigate through all of the interfaces implemented by each interface (recursively), to check those as well.  Ugly, I know.

Comment: +1 because it answers the question. As a side note, if there is some common functionality followed by the reflection for further processing based on type, you may want to implement a `Process<T>(List<T> item)` method with overloads for each possibility.  Let the compiler handle the further processing without reflection.  Although, this may not be applicable in this situation (it's not clear if `List<T>` is the only other possibility).

Comment: I like what you're getting at in the code snippet--but I'm getting false each time.  I'm passing an IList<myClass> as T, and still failing.  Second approach gives me the same issues.

Comment: Accepting this ans the answer as it completely answers my question and  solves my issue--covering enumerating the interfaces to find IList<>.  Thanks!

Comment: btw, my earlier comment--I was dealing with IList<>, and getting false, as I wasn't enumerating the interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can always just use `typeof(T)` and the `is` keyword, but I would take another look at your design.

Your approach is really defeating the purpose of a generic method.  If you have to check the type of the generic argument, well, your method isn't generic.  Generics are great for scenarios where you don't care what the underlying type is. If you care then the method shouldn't be generic, it should be overloaded (probably).  How abut telling us what you are actually trying to accomplish here so that we can give more helpful responses?

Comment: You really don't want to know.  :)   I'm creating a base query object with a method to call NHibernate's ISqlQuery.List() or ISqlQuery.UniqueResult--returning the results of the SPROC as a dynamic type.  Instead of taking the approach of "knowing" in advance, and asking the calling code to call "single" or "list", I want to help the devs by making that decision in the back end.

Comment: @jim Schubert  Yes--hadn't realized I was getting that close to reinventing the wheel.   The root of the problem is that I have to deal with SPROCs that return results that I need to convert to my business objects--but I don't want to create mappings for.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if it implements the interface IEnumerable.

```
bool isList = T is IEnumerable;
```

This will also return true if T is a Stack, Array, or other such things, but I think it'll be sufficient for your purposes.

Comment: This won't compile.  'T' is a 'type parameter' but used like a variable.

Comment: You need to add `typeof(T)` like in my example.

Comment: bool isList = typeof(T) is IEnumerable;   Returns false for T being an IList<something>

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for any built in collection, you would check for IEnumerable. That way you do not need to worry about the type parameter. However this poses a problem because string implements IEnumerable. Therefore you would need some code like this:

```
if (typeof(T) is string) {
} else if (typeof(T) is IEnumerable) {
} else { // its something else
}
```

Comment: Depending on the understanding of what is meant by a list, `IEnumerable` might cover too many things. For example, unlike `IList`, an `IEnumerable` by itself is exclusively read-only: I could e.g. implement an `IEnumerable` class that returns the Fibonacci series. Would you consider an instance of that class a list?